# SwiftUI ObservableObject - respond to Core Data changes

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, combine

For my SwiftUI view, I am trying to create an `ObservableObject` that fetches some data from a Core Data entity, and repackages it into a dictionary that I can use for the new Charts UI. The view is created just fine, but I can't figure out how to listen and respond to changes in the data. If I used a @FetchRequest directly, it would listen to the changes and respond automatically, but here I manually fetch items using a NSFetchRequest

```
class CJChartsDataDataSource: ObservableObject {

    @Published var cjCountItemsForDates = [Date: NSNumber]()        
    
    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        if let countForDates = CJDataItem.countForItemsByDate(with: context, with: Date(), andNumberOfDates: 7) {
            cjCountItemsForDates = countForDates
                            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the simplified view:

```
struct CJReportsViewController: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @ObservedObject var dataSource: CJChartsDataDataSource
    
    var body: some View {
        /// ...
    }
}
```

How do I respond to changes in this `CJDataItem` entity so that this `ObservableObject` gets updated, and so the SwiftUI view also gets the update?

Comment: You need to do it manually by subscribing to and handling NSManagedObjectContext notifications, see for instance [this article](https://www.donnywals.com/responding-to-changes-in-a-managed-object-context/)

Answer (score 1):

ObservableObject is part of Combine framework usually we don't need that when using CoreData because we don't need CombineLatest etc.

You can simply initialize the @FetchRequest with a configured NSFetchRequest instance:

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
private var quakes: FetchedResults<Quake>
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest

Note because NSFetchRequest is an object make sure to create it once somewhere and reuse it, don't create objects on demand or you'll get a SwiftUI memory leak.